# Are Betazoid cats empaths?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In Star Trek: The Next Generation season 2 episode 15, Deanna Troi mentioned that when she was a girl she had a Betazoid kitten, and that her mother and this cat did not get along well.

This led me to wonder if Betazoid cats or other native animals had similar telepathic or empathic abilities to the people there?

My premise for this question is that many terrestrial animals share common characteristics (with variations of course). Since the evolutionary process on Betazed seemed to favor the development of the telepathic empathic abilities of the local equivalent of humans, perhaps that ability derived from those people's common ancestry with Betaoid animals such as cats. If so its not hard to imagine that such common ability would have affected practices of animal husbandry, etc. as well as the social behavior of animals.

Comment: The season 7 episode "Genesis" showed that the Betazoid common ancestry is more akin to fish than cats ;)

Comment: @NKCampbell To be fair, if you trace it back far enough, we humans descended from fish ourselves, in common with all vertebrates (including cats). So descending from the Betazoid version of fish would not rule out descending from the Betazoid version of cats as well.(One thing humans are not descended from: [spiders](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155560/why-did-lt-barclay-devolve-into-a-spider))

Comment: Yes, but like Earth cats, they feed on the emotion of spite.